# ASP.NET/Jquery: document ready in update panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have the following user-control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FadingMessage.ascx.cs" Inherits="includes_FadingMessage" %>

<asp:PlaceHolder Visible="false" runat="server" ID="plhMain">
<span id="<%= this.ClientID+"_panel" %>" style="background-color:yellow; padding:10px;">
<b><%= Message %></b>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("never gets here??");
    jQuery('#<%= this.ClientID+"_panel" %>').fadeOut(1000);  
});

</script>

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Which is used in an asp:UpdatePanel. My problem is that $(document).ready is never fired?

How can I detect when a partial rendering has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a method in your head tags and then in your placeholder call it.  The problem here is that your PlaceHolder Visible="false" so it's never rendered.  If you show it dynamically via ajax the script won't run.  You'd have to rebind it when you dynamically show the placeholder.  I would suggest not using document(ready) ...